# Spawning Problems with Fuerte Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gazebo, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so I see there has been issues with spawning urdf or models in Gazebo [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/40807/problem-with-spawn_model-in-gazebo/)

so using,
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -gazebo -file `rospack find gazebo_worlds`/objects/coffee_cup.model -model coffee_cup -x 1.2 -z 1

just doesn't spawn anything... it just adds it in the models list.
Is this happening for most people? or is it an issue that can be fixed somehow?

Is there perhaps a different way to spawn objects in gazebo for Fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41646/spawning-problems-with-fuerte-ubuntu-12.04/) by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 325 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2012-08-17**:
you set your node name on startup of the launch file correct?  If so that is already set to

<node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="$(find r2_gazebo)/gazebo/r2_empty.world" output="screen"  /

**Comment by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) on 2012-08-22**:
I figured out you can spawn .xacro files.  I was able to get simple_sphere.urdf files to spawn if you change the extension to simple_sphere.xacro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were some bugs in the [spawn_model](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo/scripts/spawn_model) script, waiting for services in the wrong namespace.  This should be fixed by the next release 1.6.13.

For now, things should work if you change your gazebo node name to `gazebo`, e.g.:

```
<node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="..."/>
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0